# USB network adaptor (netgear)

Tags: 11.04, adapter

I bought a USB Network Card (Netgear N300 Wireless USB Adapter). My Ubuntu 11.04 doesn't recognize it automatically. Plus after some research I failed to find any drivers.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your card is reported to work with ndiswrapper. ndiswrapper is a tool to use the windows .INF driver, ndisgtk is a graphical front end for ndiswrapper

Assuming you have a wired internet connection

```
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 ndisgtk
```

For additional information see:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1830237

If you have the .INF on a disk or CD that came with your card, go ahead and use the one you have, otherwise the driver is attached to the second post on the forums.

See [Ubuntu Wiki Ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) for additional information on use and configuration.