# Intallation of Netgear N300 Wireless adapter on Dell Latitude D830

Tags: wireless

Can anybody assist me with installing a Netgear N300 Wireless Adapter? I've read you need the windows driver for it, but how do you get the windows driver? I've got the CD, but it wont run.

Comment: The N300 is [a DSL modem/router](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CHIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.downloads.netgear.com%2Ffiles%2FDGND3300v2_UM_14Oct10.pdf&ei=hlwDUOygDMaQ2QWa6-mOCw&usg=AFQjCNFNs2XCexzb6kL940YhYcLZ4clCfQ&sig2=zdLOdhW7lkB81N_gLiYFiQ) or a wireless router, **not a wireless adapter**. Please edit your question with the exact model number and version number from the back of the adapter, or better yet, take a photo and link it.

Answer (score 1):

izx -- it's also a [wireless USB adapter](http://www.netgear.com/service-provider/products/wireless-adapters/wireless-n/WNA3100.aspx#). That would have been obvious to you if you spent 10 seconds on google before telling the OP that the object he is currently holding in his hand doesn't exist.

To the OP: check [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86486/usb-network-adaptor-netgear). The answer there will work for 12.04, as well.